# Does OneDrive for Business support CustomAction/CommandUIExtension as in SharePoint?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I am trying to add a custom action to the ribbon on my OneDrive for Business personal page (https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username page).

As far as I know, you can extend or add custom actions, tabs or buttons to the server ribbon on SharePoint using XML. For example, this XML below could be used to add a tab with three buttons to the ribbon:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <CustomAction 
        Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.AddAButton"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Title="Add a Ribbon Button">
        <CommandUIExtension>
          <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition
              Location="Ribbon.Library.Share.Controls._children">

                <Tab Id="tab" Title="DSO">

                 <Group Id="group1" Title="DocSys Online">
                  <Button Id="OpenDSO" Label="Open">
                   Image32="https://foo.bar/images/button32.png"
                   Image16="https://foo.bar/images/button16.png">
                   <Link URL="https://foo.bar/button1" />
                  </Button>
                 </Group>

                 <Group Id="group2" Title="DocSys Online Models">
                  <Button Id="Brief" Label="Brief">
                   Image32="https://foo.bar/images/button32.png"
                   Image16="https://foo.bar/images/button16.png">
                   <Link URL="https://foo.bar/button2" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button Id="Rapport" Label="Rapport">
                   Image32="https://foo.bar/images/button32.png"
                   Image16="https://foo.bar/images/button16.png">
                    <Link URL="https://foo.bar/button3" />
                  </Button>
                 </Group>
                </Tab>

            </CommandUIDefinition>
          </CommandUIDefinitions>
        </CommandUIExtension>
      </CustomAction>
    </Elements>
```

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900938/is-there-a-client-side-javascript-library-for-onedrive-for-business-that-provide), OneDrive for Business is based on SharePoint REST and CSOM API. I see that they are using the same API structures, but when I try this out in OneDrive, the old OneDrive view shows the tab correctly and the new view doesn't show anything at all. Below is the comparison between old vs new view.

[image: Old view]

vs

[image: New view]

How can I add the custom action correctly on OneDrive? Do i miss something or is there any other way to solve this problem? Any explanations will help.

Comment: try this: http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-AddRemove-User-Custom-Actions-(in-Site-Actions-Menu)-Programmatically-using-CSOM-PNP-in-SharePoint-Office-365 but you need to find proper location

Comment: this could also help: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/custom-actions-sharepoint-add-in.md

Comment: Can this be implemented the same way in OneDrive for Business? These examples only show how to do it in SharePoint Online.

Comment: I am also looking for answer, RegistrationId should be 700, I want this to work using powershell by applying as a template.